# How can display created actions on same date?

Tags: django, orm

I have a action model for newsfeed. Like this:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target_content_type= models.ForeignKey(
                ContentType,
                related_name='target'
        )
    target = generic.GenericForeignKey(
                'target_content_type',
                'target_object_id'
        )
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def __unicode__(self):
                return "{0} {1}".format(
                        self.actor,
                        self.verb,

                        )
```

I want to show actions by one by if they created today. Bu I want to show old actions like this:

```
22.12.2013 - 2 posts created for A Blog
22.12.2013 - x followed 3 people
21.12.2013 - 3 posts created for B Blog
21.12.2013 - 4 channel created
```

This is a user's newsfeed. How can I do this according to date?

Comment: Could you post your views used for Action model?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare template context in your view, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    yesterday = datetime.today().date() - timedelta(1)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {
        'new_actions': Action.objects.filter(date__gt=yesterday),
        'old_actions_count': len(Action.objects.filter(date__lt=yesterday)),
    })
```

Then you can use the context in your template:

```
{% for action in new_actions %}
    {{ action }}
{% endfor %}
There was {{ old_actions_count }} older actions.
```

Comment: No this not gonna work. Action model have different action(following, creating, comment  vs vs)